# Integrating PayPal with React Native

Tags: react-native, paypal, venmo

I want to integrate PayPal in my application using which user can pay with PayPal and Venmo. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there isn't a single repo that is up to date and maintains by the community as far as I know. That's why your options are limited.

here are some third party libraries

1.[react-native-paypal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paypal)
2. [react-native-paypal-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paypal-lib)

if you do not want your app do be dependant on third party react native libraries then try integrating paypal with a WebView wrapper. Follow this [tutorial by medium](https://medium.com/@adityasingh_32512/integrating-paypal-in-your-react-native-app-4dcf89e11dd)

Comment: Do these packages support venmo payment?